# dock toolbar to bottom in vertical layout

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I have a view with a layout of `vertical`

```
var tray = Ti.UI.createView({
    width:deviceWidth * 0.9,
    height:'100%',
    top:0,
    left:0,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    layout:'vertical'
});
win.add(tray);
```

Inside `tray` I have a `TableView` and a `Toolbar`

```
var slideList = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    width:deviceWidth * 0.9,
    height:xxx, //--> Need to know what to do here
    top:0,
    left:0,
    search:searchList,
    filterAttribute:'searchFilter',
    backgroundColor:(Ti.Platform.osname == 'android') ? '#000000' : '#ffffff'
});
tray.add(slideList);

var iOSControls = Ti.UI.iOS.createToolbar({
    items:[flexSpace,backBtn,flexSpace,playBtn,flexSpace,linkBtn,flexSpace],
    bottom:0,
    borderTop:false,
    borderBottom:true,
    barColor:'#000'
});
tray.add(iOSControls);
```

I am not entirely sure how to size the `TableView`s `height` property so that it fills the height of `tray` minus the height of `iOSControls`. Any ideas would be appreciated..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think In iOS Device have Toolbar default Height is equal to "44px".

But, In Your case you try this code, just copy past this code in you app.

```
var tray = Ti.UI.createView({
    width:deviceWidth * 0.9,
    height:'100%',
    top:0,
    left:0,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    layout:'horizontal'
});
win.add(tray);

var iOSControls = Ti.UI.iOS.createToolbar({
    items:[flexSpace,backBtn,flexSpace,playBtn,flexSpace,linkBtn,flexSpace],
    bottom:0,
    borderTop:false,
    borderBottom:true,
    barColor:'#000'
});
tray.add(iOSControls);
var slideList = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    width:deviceWidth * 0.9,
    height:Ti.UI.FILL, //--> Need to know what to do here
    top:0,
    left:0,
    search:searchList,
    filterAttribute:'searchFilter',
    backgroundColor:(Ti.Platform.osname == 'android') ? '#000000' : '#ffffff'
});
tray.add(slideList);
```

Comment: yeah it is 44px. The code above isn't making any difference. The problem is still with the height of slide list. It fills the whole screen and covers iOSControls

Comment: I fixed it by removing the layout property in tray